# "NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)" Swift 3 Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, nsurlconnection

I'm making an app with Firebase. I was running my app when all of a sudden, I got this error:

[image]

And I got the error "NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)".

And YES, I've tried ALL of those info.plist things where it tells you to add arbitrary loads. I've tried everything out there.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>https://piigeon-7bf2d.firebaseio.com/</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.1</string>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <string>apple-sd-gothic-neo-thin-5989d270024be</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>iMedicin</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSApplicationCategoryType</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>We would like to access your photos to provide you with an amazing app experience.</string>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
    <string>UIStatusBarStyleLightContent</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>g>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSApplicationCategoryType</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>We would like to access your photos to provide you with an amazing app experience.</string>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
    <string>UIStatusBarStyleLightContent</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

That's my info.plist.

Can someone PLEASE help me? Thank you.

Comment: Regarding Info.plist: Either allow everything (`NSAllowsArbitraryLoads`) or restrict the access to specific domains, but not both. And the value for key domain is supposed to be a host (`piigeon-7bf2d.firebaseio.com`), not an URL. Please read the documentation.

Comment: Did you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: Nope, still having the same issue. I've tried everything but literally nothing works.